# Using mixed tenses in a sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses

I came across this sentence :

> When he ***started*** you ***thought*** where ***are*** they going to put him because he
>   ***doesn't*** look very good anywhere!

I feel ***are*** should change to ***were***.
Also ***doesn't*** may change to ***didn't***, but if it's expressing a general fact, should it be okay ?

Comment: This looks like an example of  free indirect speech in which mixing tenses is common. Where did you find it? Is it about a sport? https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-free-indirect-speech.php

Comment: @Shoe Thank you. I'll look it up... And yes, I've found it on today's cricket commentary [India Vs England](https://www.bbc.com/sport/live/cricket/43877750/page/3)

Answer (score 1):

If it was something someone said, then they probably were quoting "where are they going to put him, because he doesn't look very good anywhere" in which case the different tense is okay because it is something someone said in the past. If the quote was only "where are they going to put him" then yes, "doesn't" would change to "didn't". And if there was no quote, it wouldn't make sense unless the sentence were altered further.